# Javascript PHP : Droplist is not changing label according to its selection

Tags: php, javascript

I wrote following code:

```
function chkDiscount()
  {
    $pckg_value = 0;
    plan = document.getElementById("PFirst").value; 
    if (plan === "Year") { 

        document.getElementById("discount").innerHTML = "15% discount";
        <?php
            $pckg_value = ($pckg_cost - 15) * 12; 
        ?>

    }
    if (plan === "HalfYear") { 

        document.getElementById("discount").innerHTML = "10% discount";
        <?php
            $pckg_value = ($pckg_cost - 10) * 6; 
        ?>
    }
    if (plan === "Quarter") { 

        document.getElementById("discount").innerHTML = "5% discount";
        <?php
            $pckg_value = ($pckg_cost - 5) * 3; 
        ?>
    }
  }
```

I m using the $pckg_value in rest of the code.But its shows me same value on each selection.i.e. alwayes shows value calculated in last if block.Please help me to show right calculation on each selection.Please help.

Comment: why are you using PHP in javascript?

Comment: As i see it's JS code ... how come you write $pckg_value at line 3 , 9 in php and JS the same ..... it's different .

Comment: Bcoz i want show exact calculation on change of droplist selection.

Answer (score 0):

The way it's written it will never work. Regardless of the JavaScript if block, all the php blocks will execute since JavaScript can't control php logic. What you need to do is set the value of $pckg_value using JavaScript only, or change the whole thing to use php for determining the value.